# Eagle eye or Eagle's eye?

Tags: nouns, possessives

There was a movie in 2008 called Eagle Eye. What is the difference between

- Eagle eye
- Eagle's eye

Comment: I think Eagle's eye is technically wrong. Since it's a singular count noun and need an article. Eagle in Eagle eye on the other hand is an attributive noun and acts like an adjective.

Comment: I stiil don't understand

Comment: An _**eagle's eye**_ shows a possessive relationship. _It's an eye that belongs to an eagle_. _**Eagle eye**_ can refer to a person's eye that has a good eyesight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***'S*** can be used to show that something belongs to an animal or a bird as in

> Measurements taken from a *lion's* paw print can help us guess how old it is and also if it is a male or female.

In your example we can use *eagle's eye* as *an eye that belongs to an eagle* as in

> An eagle's eye is as big as a human's.

In this general sense you can use *eagle eye* with no real change in meaning as in

> The eagle eye is among the strongest in the animal kingdom.

However if you want to refer to a specific eagle, use the possessive form as in

> That eagle's left eye is pink.

Also *eagle eye* can have a figurative sense, too which means *a keen or close watch* or *a person who has sharp vision or maintains a keen watchfulness* as in

> she was keeping an eagle eye on Leni.
>
> He's an eagle eye when it comes to top notch guitars.

which I think is probably the intended meaning of the movie title.